# Problems including OpenImaJ in Jar file with maven

Tags: java, maven, openimaj

I have been developing a very simple maven application and I have been trying to run `mvn package` so I can generate the jar file.

Running `mvn package` seems to be working but I am having issues running this `java -jar myApp.jar`.

I get this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openimaj/image/Image
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openimaj.image.Image
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

My application code:

```
import org.openimaj.image.DisplayUtilities;
import org.openimaj.image.FImage;
import org.openimaj.image.ImageUtilities;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageUtilities.readF(new File("test.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DisplayUtilities.display(image);
    }

}
```

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>image-processing</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.openimaj</groupId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you check that the lib directory is actually in the same place as the `myApp.jar` file? It looks like your `pom.xml` is setup to put the libraries in `target/classes/lib` and the output jar in `target` whilst the manifest entry indicates that `lib` is in the same directory as the jar.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. The myApp.jar is under target/ . all the other jar files are under target/lib/. I tried putting them in the same folder but I get them same. What is the correct approach in this? or the usual way of doing things when it comes to generating jars?

Comment: I always tend to make fat jars that contain all the dependencies in a single file - usually using the maven assembly (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or maven shade (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin. See the first section of the OpenIMAJ tutorial (http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/getting-started-with-openimaj-using-maven.html) for how to automatically generate a pom file that contains both the OpenIMAJ libs as well as a configuration for the assembly plugin.